# Using javax.ws.rs.core.Context with fabric3

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0

I am trying to implement a ContainerRequestFilter for a RESTful web service with fabric3v2.5.3. I have the filter working, but I need to grab the ip address in the request. I have tried using

```
   @Context
   HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

But it throws a null pointer exception when trying access the HttpServletRequest. We are using the built in jersey 2.13 that comes with the JAX-RS fabric3 extension. Is there a way to get the @Context to work within fabric3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Context injection support will be added in Fabric 3.0 and is not available in previous versions.

For versions earlier than Fabric3 3.0, you can retrieve the HTTP servlet request and response objects via an injected `Fabric3RequestContext`:

```
 public class SomeFilter implements .... {

   @Context
   protected F3RequestContext context;

   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
       HttpServletRequest req =  
            context.getHeader(HttpServletRequest.class, "fabric3.httpRequest");
   }
}
```